# passing a veriable in a class base component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am very a beginner at `Javascript`, `ES6` and `ReactNative`.  I have a class component called `Input`. there I have a method (`handleTextLayout`) in which I get the width of my `Text`. I need to use that number inside the render method, let's say i want to show how big the text it. How can I have a class variable and the then change it in that method and pass it in other places in the class? Below is what I tried (besides many other things) but it doesn't work.

```
class Input extends Component {

  constructor(){
      super();
      Input.TextWidth = '11111';
  }



  handleTextLayout(evt){    
    Input.TextWidth = evt.nativeEvent.layout.width;
  }


  render(){

    const { label, placeholder, onChangeText, value }  = this.props;
    const { inputStyle, labelStyle, viewContainerStyle } = myInputStyle ;

    return(
      <View style={ viewContainerStyle } >

        <Text style={ labelStyle }  onLayout={this.handleTextLayout.bind(this)}>
          { Input.TextWidth }
        </Text>

        <TextInput
          style={ inputStyle }
          placeholder={ placeholder }
          onChangeText={ onChangeText }
          value={ value }
          autoCorrect={false}
        />

      </View>
    );
  };
};
```

it still shows that `11111` in the Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT

Some folks in comments pointed out mistakes in this code - I fixed those now, thanks!

---

I don't know anything about React Native but I assume this works the same as in React.

I guess what you could do is to create a state and save that width there. 
Then in the `handleTextLayout` method you set state to new value.

so:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    textWidth: '11111'
  };
  this.handleTextLayout.bind(this); // a good practice
}
```

and then

```
handleTextLayout(evt){    
  this.setState({ textWidth: evt.nativeEvent.layout.width });
}
```

and finally in render:

```
<Text style={ labelStyle } onLayout={this.handleTextLayout}>
  { this.state.textWidth }
</Text>
```

This will work because `setState` will re-render the component so it shows new value.

Comment: Yep, this is what he's missing. I'd definitely also mention that you must pass `props` to `super()` when overriding a component constructor. And you should also bind handlers in the `constructor()` and not in `render()`.

Comment: Could also use arrow functions instead of bind (my preference). `onLayout={() => this.handleTextLayout()}`. Either way, they all get the job done.

Comment: @apieceofbart Small fix (in addition to props passing bowheart mentioned): `setState` should be `this.setState`.

Comment: just one more question, what if i want to use that this.state.textWidth in my style? something like :` labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    borderWidth:    this.state.textWidth ,
    borderColor: '#ff0066'
  }`

Comment: @JeffM i used your fat arrow function instead of the bind but i again got 111, but when i use the bind i get 34 which is the right number for the text, why?

Comment: @farmcommand2 You still also need to use state and setState. The arrow function by itself isn't the solution. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class